# PHP MYSQL when user logs in, insert the password as a variable to a different database?

Tags: php, mysql, parameters, passwords

I want users that have access to my website to be able to use their login credentials on my new website without them having to do anything such as register again, so what I'm doing is that whenever they log in to my old website this is the login form:

```
<?php

require_once(PROJECTS_PATH . '/path/to/Form.php');
class UserLogin extends Form {

var $focusFirst = 'email';

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->input('email')->required("Please enter your email (or 
login).")->label("Email (or login)")->width(40);
    $this->password('password')->required("Please enter your password.");
    $this->link('cancel', '/user/redirect', array("style" => "padding- 
right: 50px;"))->label('Cancel');
    $this->submit('login'); #, array('value' => 'Login'));
    require ('/path/to/scripts/updateUsers.php'); //This includes the script that creates a new user for my new site
}
}
?>
```

I've tried bunch of different ways and it doesn't seem to work out..
What works is I'm able to take all the informations needed from the user to create a new user in my db for my new site but I can't get the password passed I want to get it raw to my updateUsers script and in that script I'm hashing it.

NOTE: I can't just move my db user table to my new site table because there are different hashing involved.

my updateUsers script:

```
<?php
$firstname = $user['first_name'];
$mail  = $user['email'];
$pw = 'TestPasswor'; //I'm doing this right not which works but I need the actual user's pw otherwise this is useless

include("/path/to/password.inc"); //for hashing the pw 
include("/path/to/bootstrap.inc");
$hashed_password = user_hash_password(trim($pw));

$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO test_db.users (name, pass, mail, status)
VALUES ('$firstname', '$hashed_password', '$mail', '1')",
mysql_real_escape_string($firstname),
mysql_real_escape_string($hashed_password),
mysql_real_escape_string($mail));

// Perform Query
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>
```

Sorry I know this is a long description but thanks!

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: What do you mean by *"but I can't get the password passed"*? You mean you cannot select it?

Comment: @JayBlanchard what I'm trying to get at is how do I pass it after user enters it to get it in plain text so I can hash it for my other website

Comment: You want to pass it from one domain to another?

Comment: Where do you set `$user`? Does it have a `password` field?

Comment: If you're using different hashing schemes on the two sites, you need the login code to put the unhashed password into `$user['password']`.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you! I realized I was trying to pass the password in the wrong .php file I needed to do it in the file that processes the password hashing, so I was trying this whole time to pass a hashed password which resulted in not working.

Comment: Don´t use your own password hash for password. Use PHP built in function password_hash and password_verify